# JSON.stringify in jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I use `document.write()` for json. work in `document.write(JSON.stringify({name:'jason',surname:'etc'}));` outside the ajax, but not work in `.done()`. I tried remove `dataType:'json'` but not work.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://api.wunderground.com/api/24b969202160514e/geolookup/conditions/q/Turkey/zmw:00000.58.17352.json",
    dataType:'json'
})
.done(function(data) {
    console.log("success",data);
    document.write(JSON.stringify(data));
    //document.write(data);
})
.fail(function(data) {
    console.log("error",data);
})
.always(function() {
    console.log("complete");
});
```

Comment: try out `success` instead of `done`

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp I think probably you cant use document.write after document ready. You can use jquery to modify or append the content to some element in your page.

Comment: @prasanth i try but not work. actually code is work, but i want write the raw json on the page. it write in html>body. but it write raw json outside success or done function. how to write raw json on the page. without html>body.

Comment: Use some element with print as a text. `$('some element').text(yourjsonstring)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use jQuery's [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)?

```
$.getJSON('https://api.wunderground.com/api/24b969202160514e/geolookup/conditions/q/Turkey/zmw:00000.58.17352.json')
.done(function(data) {
    console.log("success",data);
    document.write(JSON.stringify(data));
    //document.write(data);
})
```

Comment: actually code is work, but i want write the raw json on the page. it write in html>body. but it write raw json outside success or done function.

Answer (score 1):

If you check your browsers console, you should see the following error ...

`jquery-git.js:9648 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://jsfiddle.net/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/24b969202160514e/geolookup/conditions/q/Turkey/zmw:00000.58.17352.json'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Change your url to protocol from `http` to `https`.

`https://api.wunderground.com/api/24b969202160514e/geolookup/conditions/q/Turkey/zmw:00000.58.17352.json`

That should work.

[Working Demo](https://jsbin.com/tutiyovumu/edit?js,output)

Comment: I can't get any error in console. I change http to https but not work.

Comment: @bukalemun, check the link